# Detect Rails (zeitwerk) class unloading programatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if there is a way to detect when a class is being reloaded in the development environement.

I am trying to create a static thread map, but it wait until all threads finish before fully unloading everything.

In such a case, I would like to kill the threads (or send them an interrupt?).

Thanks

EDIT:
What i am trying to achieve is something like:

```
class StaticThreadController
  @@x = 0
  @@threads = [] # static storage

  # dummy function is adding a thread to a list
  def execute
    @@x += 1

    # dummy thread code
    @@threads << Thread.new do
      Rails.application.executor.wrap do
        (1..100).each do |n|
          puts @@x
          sleep 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # function is called when unloading the class
  def before_unload
    @@threads.each do |t|
      Thread.kill(t)
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: What are you calling "reloading" of a class? Can you provide some simple code to explain what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What would be causing the "reloading" of the class ? An explicit TERM signal ? I may be wrong because I don't know much about Ruby's internals but IMHO your static class will never be "unloaded" until the script ends. Because it is a "static" class it also make things harder. BTW, you can do some experiments with the module `ObjectSpace` to see when the class is destroyed.

Comment: When using the development environment, Rails reload class on new requests. I am trying to detect that. I have done some tests, even statics are reloaded (since @@x will come back to 0).

Comment: It's more like the class is "loaded" for each request, but whatever. I far as I can understand, what you want is to kill the threads launched by this class in a previous request when a new request arrives?

Comment: Not exactly. The class static context is reloaded if you make any changes to the code. But if you don't touch anything, the static do not move. I am trying to detect this.

Comment: On a side note class variables are not considered thread safe. Use class instance variables - `@threads = []` instead. https://morioh.com/p/cd58d8ebda56

Comment: Thanks for that. But do you have an idea for my question?